# RoR fb_graph application feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using fb_graph gem for Ruby on Rails. I want to post a message on wall but the problem is that when I post the message (feed) it is posted by my user instead of my application, on the application's wall..

```
so it looks like
   Name Surname
   message content
   via application_name
and I want it to be
    application_name
    message content
```

My code is:

```
application = FbGraph::Application.new(app_id).fetch
application.feed!(:message => 'test', :access_token => access_token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to this question. I have generated access token for application instead of user. This can be found on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/